# Responsive grid with @angular/flex-layout, @angular/material and mat-card with images?

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-material, css-grid, angular-flex-layout

I've got a basic layout like this:

```
   Cell 0     Cell 1      Cell 2 <!-- these are not to appear in actual render
 __________________________________
 | Image 0  | Image 1  | Image 2  |
 |----------| Image 1  |-----------
 | text here| Image 1  | text here|
 ----------------------------------
   Cell 3     Cell 4      Cell 5 <!-- these are not to appear in actual render
 __________________________________
 | Image 3  | Image 4  | Image 5  |
 |----------|----------| Image 5  |
 | text here| text here| Image 5  |
 ----------------------------------
```

Depending on the screen size, there should be 4 cells, 3 cells, 2 cells, or 1 cell, per row.

The image should take up the entire cell, and be aligned—in size—with images in other cells.

Some of my attempts: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gk58tk

Is this an uncommon use-case for grids, mat-card, and similar?

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Okay, I'm working on a Stack Snippet. Are there any examples with Angular? - I tried posting the rendered output but it gave me a character limit error.

Comment: Although you already solved the problem, I wanted to share this article which looks really promising in this sense (I did not have a chance to test it, but reading through it I can say it is very related to the question): https://zoaibkhan.com/blog/create-a-responsive-card-grid-in-angular-using-flex-layout-part-1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a solution, I do not know exactly if that's what you're looking for:

```
<div fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="10px" ngClass.gt-xs="ml-10">
  <mat-card fxFlex.sm="0 1 calc(50%-10px)" fxFlex.md="0 1 calc(33%-10px)" fxFlex.gt-md="0 1 calc(25%-10px)">
    <mat-card-title>Card 1</mat-card-title>
    <img mat-card-image src="https://kakiseni.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/250X250.png" class="image">
    <mat-card-content>Primary card content. Intended for blocks of text</mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>Container for buttons at the bottom of the card</mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>

  <mat-card>...</mat-card>
</div>
```

I used `fxLayout="row wrap"` for the list of cards and depending on the size of the screen, there is between 1 to 4 cards per line.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-responsive-grid-flex-layout-and-mat-card-with-img)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just tried this and got a lot further than before. Upvoting. The SVGs are going over border of the mat-card. How can that be solved?

Comment: Maybe by setting a size on your image with `max-height` an `max-width`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Really worked for me. Yes, I made some changes in percentage as per my requirement but yes this is awesome!